# Are there any cases where the source transformation method can't be applied?

Tags: current, thevenin, analysis, norton

When I tried to use the source transformation method on the 12 V voltage source I got the wrong answer. If I transformed the 2 A current source it worked just fine.

Are there any cases when deducing Norton and Thévenin equivalents where I can't use the source transformation method?

The right answer using Norton is -0.4 A.

[image]

Comment: Show your work.  It should work just fine, my guess is you made a simple mistake somewhere.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you got wrong, but notice that *i* in the diagram is not the same as the Norton source current.

Comment: The transformations always work. They are not always helpful, without first transforming back, again. But they always work. There is pretty solid theory behind them. How exactly did you work things out doing the transformation on the 12 V source and its series resistance? Show what you did there. I'm curious how you applied it to get a result.

Comment: The question is asking for i which is -2.4A. The Norton current is what is -0.4A, not the i. These numbers match simulation and two methods for calculating the Norton current (though I had to try several times because I kept making dumb mistakes).

Answer (score 2):

> My question here, Is there any Cases in Deducing Norton and Thevenin equivalents where I cannot use source transformation method?

- There is no Thevenin equivalent for an ideal current source.
- There is no Norton equivalent for an ideal voltage source.

Any other linear one-port network (meaning a network of linear resistors, ideal voltage and current sources, and linear dependent sources) will have an I-V curve from which either a Thevenin or Norton equivalent circuit can be found.

Comment: Even in those cases it is possible to use such transformations, as long as you are comfortable dealing with limits to infinity as part of your circuit analysis Arsenal.

Comment: @EdgarBrown, sorry, who are you replying to?

Comment: If this is a comment on my answer, then think about the Thevenin equivalent of an ideal current source. It would have to have both the voltage source and the series resistance going to infinity. While you could mathematically define such a thing, you'd basically have to use the Norton circuit to do so (taking V and R to infinity while maintaining V/R = I). And it wouldn't be a useful way to simplify a circuit analysis.

Comment: Having several elements on a circuit going to infinity is not a problem, as long as you know what you are doing. I once had a student that had all the theoretical aspects down solid, but was too lazy to remember the more common rules of thumb for op-amp feedback. He had no problem manipulating all those infinite elements within the circuit and got a full grade in the exam. A schematic is just a shorthand form for a set of equations that makes it easier to manipulate them.

Comment: @EdgarBrown, That's true (and it's why I said "you could mathematically define such a thing" in my comment), but it only makes sense to make a Thevenin or Norton equivalent of your circuit, if it actually makes analyzing the circuit simpler. If it makes the analysis more complicated, why bother to do it?

Comment: Knowing you can make a Thevenin equivalent for an ideal current source is book-smart. Actually doing it when trying to solve a circuit is when people start calling you book-smart as a backhanded compliment.

Comment: There are conditions in which using the infinite elements might make the analysis (and particularly understanding) easier. We do it all the time with frequency and resistors in many circuits, and even when using opamps in an unfamiliar configuration.

Comment: There's neither Thevenin equivalent of an ideal current source nor Norton equivalent of an ideal voltage source. Period.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to source transform a lone ideal source.  Other than that, you can use it for pretty much anything.  However, I will also note that the layout of the circuit will definitely determine what makes the most sense.

What you have to look at is what you get after performing the transformation, and whether or not that will help simplify the circuit.  Thevenin equivalents are series while Norton equivalents are parallel, so you have to look at where changing series elements into parallel or vise-versa will help.  Generally, if you have two blocks in series, try to transform them to thevenin equivalents so you can combine the sources and resistances.  If you have two blocks in parallel, use the Norton equivalent so the sources and resistances can be combined in parallel.

In this case, transforming the 2A source and 4 ohm resistor, then combining with the 12V source and 6 ohm resistor, then transforming one more time to get a norton equivalent is probably the most straightforward sequence.  You can source transform the 6 ohm and 12 volt sources first, but that doesn't really make combining elements much easier.

Answer (score 1):

According to my calculations the answer should be 2.4A though, not - 0.4A. I've also confirmed this by simulation.

Comment: Showing some calculations is highly desirable.

Comment: The OP phrased the post badly. The questions asks for i but the OP said the Norton current is supposed to be -0.4A, which does match simulation and my hand calculations. The answer the question is asking for i=-2.4A

Answer (score 0):

Norton and Thévenin theorems are theorems as such: given the postulates, they are a necessary conclusion.

The postulates include linearity, so we can easily break the theorems with that.  If we consider the impedance of a diode, its impedance is a (nonlinear) function of the applied current.  The theorems make no claim with respect to applied voltage or current, i.e. the resistance and voltage are independent of load conditions.  Which is to say, they are not functions of V (or I).  This is proof enough that a diode does not, in general, obey these theorems.

(Normally, this sort of situation is dealt with by *linearizing* the system, i.e., considering a small change around the nominal operating point, then taking the limit as ΔI (or ΔV) → 0.)

### On Infinity

Some complain about infinities or zeroes when transforming an ideal source; that's good enough of a conclusion for -- for lack of a better word, intermediate level studies, I guess?  It is not a necessary conclusion, though: later one may learn that infinity and zero are merely complements on a whole continuum: the set of real numbers forms a field (a set of numbers which is closed under the four arithmetic operations: +, -, *, /).  There is no ambiguity about dividing by zero, or multiplying by infinity: in a circuit, an infinite resistance simply means zero change in current for a change in voltage, and the vice versa is true about zero.

Indeed, we can even create resistances near zero, or infinity, plus or minus, with a real (active) circuit (such as an impedance converter), adjusted to exhibit such behavior.  Indeed, component tolerances and noise give us a natural ambiguity, where we can never have a perfectly infinite resistance, but it will always be a finite value, large, but a little bit positive or negative (or likewise, close to but not exactly zero).

The key insight is that, under the \$x \rightarrow 1/x\$ transformation, positive and negative infinity are equivalent to zero.  The same ambiguities that prevent a real circuit from approaching an ideal zero, are the same which prevent it from approaching ideal infinity.

It's commonly taught that division by zero is undefined, because the limit on both sides does not match.  This is not at all incorrect: it matters very much for the precise rigors of mathematics.  But it is also not useful for circuit analysis, where both infinities are equivalent: the change in current is zero (±) regardless of how much voltage change you put into it!

The freedom to invert zero and infinity becomes more developed in AC analysis, where complex numbers are used, and the reciprocal operation is a map between points near zero, and points near infinity; we even have names for them: impedance is the reciprocal of admittance, \$Z = 1/Y\$, the complex elements of which are resistance \$R\$ and reactance \$X\$ (\$Z = R + jX\$), and conductance and susceptance (\$Y = G + jB\$).  If you like, you might imagine infinity as a halo around the complex plane, which (on inversion) is equivalent to the points near zero (and vice versa).

Note in the complex case, we are sensitive to direction (because complex numbers have a direction, or angle, or phase), except at precisely zero/infinity where the direction might be considered "all" for our purposes.

Calculus, especially complex analysis and vector calculus, is very particular about how a variable approaches limits such as these; but they deal with functions much more general than these as well -- exponentiation (or its inverse) and special functions.  Whereas, in the polynomial space that lumped-equivalent circuits reside in, things are not so picky, so these conclusions are valid for our purposes.